# Call to undefined function in GetEntityManager() in cli-config.php

Tags: orm, doctrine, mapping, entitymanager, undefined-function

I tried installing doctrine2 orm from composer, it was successfull, I setup my bootstrap.php as shown below

```
<?php
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
// bootstrap.php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array(ROOT.DS.'library'.DS.'doctrine/entities/');
$isDevMode = false;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
'user'     => 'root',
'password' => '',
'dbname'   => 'meso',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

?>
```

and here is my cli-config.php

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

// replace with file to your own project bootstrap
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

// replace with mechanism to retrieve EntityManager in your app
$entityManager = GetEntityManager();

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);

?>
```

When I tried creating orm mapping into my entities folder using the command below on cli, it throws this error "Call to undefined function in GetEntityManager() in cli-config.php on line 8"

```
  >  php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping xml ./path/to/entities/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution to my problem, I havent created a getEntitymanager function that calls for EntityManager instance. I did that in my bootstrap.php

Answer (score 7):

It is enough if you put only this code into the `cli-config.php`, because you have already defined the `$entityManager` and assigned a value to it in the bootstrap.

```
<?php

// cli-config.php
require_once "bootstrap.php";

return \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```